# how to create a Go-Back button inside a drill down chart using Kendo

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I need to create Drill Down chart using kendo ,the problem i have is how should i add a button inside for step back ,for example in the following demo :

HTML:

```
<div id="chart" style="float:left"></div>
```

Java Script:

```
    $("#chart").kendoChart({
      series: [{
        data: [1, 2],
        color: function(point) {
          if (point.value > 1) {
            return "red";
          }
        }
      }],

      seriesClick:seriesClick

    });

      function seriesClick(){
      $("#chart").kendoChart({
      series: [{
        data: [1, 1],
      }], 
    });

      }
```

when you click on the chart,it drills down another chart but there is no way back to the main chart:

DEMO:

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sqd6v0db/7/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just undo the last chart you have created with the previous one using this button:

```
$('<button>Back</button>')
    .on("click", function() {
    createChart();
    $(this).remove();
})
.appendTo($('body'));
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sqd6v0db/19/)

Comment: Thanks for the solution,just one more thing ,if also the second chart has a to be drilled down,if i use this approach i will get two Back button,what should i do ?

Comment: @mrslt there are many ways for achieve that, but I think the way you're doing might not be the best approach depending on how you fetch your charts data, or how bigger the data is. However, [check this](http://jsfiddle.net/sqd6v0db/45/), it may help you out.

Comment: thanks a million,since you are experienced i would be grateful if you tell me a reasonable approach,i get the data i show it on a chart and by clicking on each bar i get another subgroup of the clicked bar in another chart,so thought instead of that better try drill down chart,now im still not sure if its a good approach but i would like to know your idea,thanks in advance

Comment: @mrslt I mean a "good approach" on how to handle the data itself, the way 
 you display them I think it is pretty nice. If your data is all local, then it is easier, you could create each chart on separate `div`s and hide and show the current viewing chart as user navigates, or get the same chart instance, set the new data to it's data source and refresh it. I don't like too much re-creating a chart over another one, at least [`destroy`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart/methods/destroy) it before or something like that. anyway, you're welcome.